# How to create Composite Unique Constraint in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, constraints

Preferably I would like to know how to do it using the SQL Server Management Studio interface but that isn't completely necessary. If you simply have a script to add one after a table is made that would be fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In SQL Server Management Studio

- goto the Object Explorer
- pick your table and open its designer (can't remember what it was called in 2005 - Modify Table or something?)
- in the table designer, pick the "Manage Indexes and Keys" icons from the toolbar (the table with the little key)
- in there, add a new index and give it a name, click it's "Unique" setting

[image]

- open the list of columns in the index definition and add your columns you want to thave in the index

[image]

That's it! :)

Comment: Cool. It seems strange that this is in the indexes section instead of the constraints section

Comment: A Unique Constraint is basically handled by a Unique Index - that's why.

Answer (score 30):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableName 
ADD CONSTRAINT
ConstraintName UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
    Column01,
    Column02,
    Column03
)
```

I use business names for constraints so that if it is violated and an exception bubbles up, I get "*Only one Dept per Employee violation*" in my error message rather than "*ConstraintXXX violation*".